# Display posts, category name and post-comments in 1 query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables in my database:

- `posts`
- `categories` and
- `comments`.

I want to display columns from the 3 tables in one query. Right now I'm only displaying columns from `posts` and `categories` tables. But I also want to display the comments on each post which have the same `post_id`.

The three tables includes these columns:

```
POSTS
    id, cat_id, title, contents, image, date_posted

CATEGORIES
    id, name, date

COMMENTS
    id, post_id, name, comment, date
```

I have this MySQL query right now:

```
SELECT
    posts.id AS post_id,
    categories.id AS category_id,
    title,
    contents,
    image,
    date_posted,
    categories.name
FROM posts
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = posts.cat_id;
```

But I also want to display comments in each post and I don't know how to change the query.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the implementation, if you want to retrieve all data in one query:

```
SELECT posts.id AS post_id, categories.id AS category_id, title, contents, image, date_posted, categories.name, comments.name as comments, comments.comment, comments.date
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = posts.cat_id
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = posts.post_id 
WHERE post_id =...
```

You should `LEFT JOIN` comments because even if there are no comments you still get results.

Comment: This won't return posts that don't have any comments. The last join should be changed to LEFT JOIN. Moreover, such solution will require some grouping done on application level as every post will be returned as many times as many comments it has in the database but it's something that can't be avoided easily if you want to have everything in one query.

Comment: I'd just like to add that post data will be duplicated for every category/comment, so make sure to only use the data once.